# combining rss feeds in python

Tags: python, json, rss

How can I combine multiple rss feeds in python to convert them to a single JSON file?

```
import urllib.request
import xmltodict
import json

url = "https://www.feedforall.com/sample.xml"

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    data_dict = xmltodict.parse(response.read())
    json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)
    with open("data.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(json_data)
        json_file.close()
    response.close()
```

This code can already do the job but only with one url

Comment: this will not create a json file with proper format!

Comment: i just need to know how to combine multiple rss feeds together

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the url as an array and use for loop to use multiple urls**

```
urls = ["link1","link2"]
for url in urls:
    /*rest of your code */
```

**and then append all data to a new array and you can have a combined array**